# how was this angle found?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

This is a solution from a book involving trusses (in statics), I don't understand how they found the angle $\theta$. What is their method?

[image]

This is the given problem:
[image]

(the given lengths differ a bit between the problem in the book and the solution manual)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the horizontals from $A$ and $B$.  Note that $AB=6$.  The right triangle with hypotenuse $\overline{BD}$ and horizontal/vertical legs has an angle of $30^\circ$ between the hypotenuse and horizontal leg and its horizontal leg is $16$, so its vertical leg is $16\tan30^\circ$.  Looking at the comparable triangle with hypotenuse $\overline{AL}$, the vertical leg is $24\tan25^\circ$.

So, the right triangle with angle $\theta$ at $D$ and hypotenuse $\overline{DL}$ has vertical leg $6+16\tan30^\circ-24\tan25^\circ$, so $$\tan\theta=\frac{6+16\tan30^\circ-24\tan25^\circ}{8}.$$

Comment: i finally see it!